# How to make the database structure extensible for a turn based game?

Tags: database, structure, effects

I'm working on a fantasy turn base game.
I now have to create the database structure for my spells. The problem is that I don't really have a good idea on how to create it. Maybe the effects of those spells should not be stored in a database?

For instance, effects could be; increase attack, pull an enemy, heal, teleport, hide, put a mine and so on... Effects are pretty different and I would like the database structure to be extensible.

### Edit:

It's a turn based game, time is the same as turns and distance represents the squares.
Some examples of what I mean below.

Let's say we have Incinerate:

- it can target only 1 enemy (not ally)
- it can be casted at a distance of 3 squares
- it deals 5 damage per turn
- it lasts 3 turns

Now we can take Shock Wave:

- it travels in a line for 4 squares
- it starts from a square near the caster
- it damages the first target it hits (ally or enemy)
- it deals 5 damage to the target and knocks it back 1 square

And the last one Rain Call:

- it can be casted at any distance
- it's a cloud the size of a 5x5 square
- it can target both ally and enemies
- only fire creatures take damage
- while casting the caster is immobilized and it loses 5 mana/turn

As you can see there are a lot of possible columns: the distance it travels, turns, casting distance, type (damage, heal, armor, etc), value (+2), target (enemy, ally, both), size, etc.

Comment: How about storing a string which can be parsed? Something like "ATT+2", "HEAL+2".

Comment: As @forcemagic says your question is pretty large. Too large. You need to go away create something you think might work. Test it. Find out it's negative points and then come back with a well-worded question about where you're going wrong and asking for help to fix it.

Comment: Amit Bhargava: Thank you for your answer, it's a good suggestion but I'd say without the +2. Let's say there are 2 fields: type (ATK, HEAL, etc) and value (+2). And thanks for your answer as well @Ben, I will indeed test the solution I will decide on, but I still think I need some more suggestions, I think your suggestions are good but maybe "too large" as you said...

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a relational database for storing spells. Relational databases are good in cases when most of the following conditions apply:

- you have very large amount of data,
- the data can logically be organized as n-ary relations (tables, rows, columns),
- you have many users that access to the data concurrently,
- you need [ACID properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID),
- et cetera

Databases are like trucks. They are big. They are difficult to use. They are expensive. (in terms of needed expertise, maintenance time, run time efficiency, etc. if not monetarily) They are very good at what they are good at, but not at anything else. Don't use a truck when a bicycle would suffice.

Let's come to your problem. The number of different *types* of spells is surely bounded and known at compile time, why don't you define an interface ISpell, and let each spell type be a class that implements ISpell? (You can also define an abstract class for common code) Then a SpellFactory may construct and provide access to all the spells when the program starts. Do you really need the spells be accessible from outside independent of your code?

If hard coding a SpellFactory is not flexible enough for your purposes, you can use xml configuration files. `<spell type="blind" description="bla bla" picture="file.jpg"> <effects> <effect .. /> .. </effects> <range>5</range>` etc. I don't know much about computer games, but this is what they did in sid meier civilization game, for example. Then, instead of hard coding the different spells in the SpellFactory, you can let it read them from the configuration file at the start up.

As far as I can see, using configuration files instead of a database has the following advantages:

- It is a fast, easy, lightweight solution,
- It is much more flexible than having all the spells having the same set of columns, (most of which will not make sense for a specific spell)
- It is much easier to have more than one version of set of spells at the same time, for experiments, variations, etc,
- You can let end users access and manipulate xml files for customizing the game without letting them access the database that would also contain sensitive data,
- et cetera.

The disadvantages:

- More people know about relational databases than xml format, so you might need a couple of hours to learn how to read and manipulate xml "elements".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty large. It depends on a lot of things, are you going to load the spell during runtime? Maybe you will load them at the beginning of the game? What database will you be using?

[Amit Bhargava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219487/amit-bhargava)'s suggestion is good and has the advantage of being *user-understandable*. However string are pretty slow, so what you could do is **use flags in your spell table**. Then, based on the flag you know which type of spell it is.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I updated my question hopping it will be a little more clear. To answer your questions: This is only for the logic part and it will only be loaded when needed (the UI is loaded when there's a possibility those spells will be used). The database I'm using is HRDB from Google App Engine. I will take in consideration all of your suggestions and try something for myself maybe I can find a good database structure.